# python manage.py dumpdata Unable to serialize database

Tags: python, django, dumpdata

I am trying to run the command
`python manage.py dumpdata > data.json`

However, I receive such a traceback:

```
CommandError: Unable to serialize database: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1-4: character maps to <undefined>
Exception ignored in: <generator object cursor_iter at 0x0000020E11353820>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Illia\Desktop\MyDjangoStuff\greatkart\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1625, in cursor_iter
    cursor.close()
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried dumping with django-admin instead?

Comment: It gets me a traceback saying that I need to define DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE first, but when I run django-admin dumpdata > json.data --settings greatkart.settings
it says 'no module named "greatkart"', despite the fact it is the name of my project

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Running `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` before `python manage.py dumpdata > data.json` has solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

if this doesn't work, and if you are windows, try

```
python -Xutf8 ./manage.py dumpdata > data.json
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't get the soloution above to work, however i did get this to work;

https://pypi.org/project/django-dump-load-utf8/

I installed it and used its command for dumping data and it worked, hope this helps anybody else! I think my problem was that my database had Norwegian letters in it "ÆØÅ"

Comment: some context&explanations would be a minimum

Comment: I don't know what is worst, this answer or the linked package "django-dump-load-utf8" which the author says he was not able to contribute to Django itself and decided to create a new package because the Django's "contribution guide is too long to read".

Comment: Oh sorry, I legitimately meant what I said. The solution given on this subject did not solve foreign characters, however this package did. Just wanted to tell in case anyone else had the same problem.